# How do I get the current date in SQL when entering data to a microsoft database?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select

I am using Microsoft SQL Server and SQL Server Management Studio.

I have a column called `dateApplied` which has a constraint like this:

```
[dateApplied] >= getDate()
```

When I enter a row the date is automatically added the row.

My problem is when I use the `SELECT` function, the `dateApplied` column is automatically changed to the current date and time in which the `SELECT` statement is called.

How do I prevent this from happening?

Thanks
Peter

Comment: Can you post the table structure?  The value of the `dateApplied` should not change on `SELECT`

Comment: use a trigger instead of a getDate constraint

Comment: What **kind** of constraint is this? A **default** constraint? A **check** constraint??

Comment: I think it is a check constraint, I think that might be the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you're using a computed column, like:

```
create table t1 
    (
    id int
,   date_col as getdate()
    )
```

Try a default constraint instead:

```
create table t1 
    (
    id int
,   date_col datetime constraint DF_T1_DateCol default getdate() not null
    )
```

A computed column is calculated whenever you run a query.  A default constraint is only generated when the row is first inserted.

Comment: Because I am using SQL server, I am using the user interface to build tables, not the query code itself. Is there a a way to alter the table and add that constraint using the GUI?

Comment: In SSMS, you can use the `Default Value` property to create a default constraint.  The computed column is under `Computed Column Specification`.

Comment: I just tried that there beofre you posted it.  That has solved the problem!